# How can I use a MediaBrowserService with a widget?

Tags: android, service, widget, media

My service extends the MediaBrowserService class and it responds to certain MediaController actions such as `getMediaController().getTransportControls().onPlay()`. However, I didn't find a way to "control" my service from a Widget, because the MediaController class isn't available from it. How can I communicate with my service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use a [MediaButtonReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html), which will forward commands to your `MediaBrowserService`, where you can then handle them by adding a call to [MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html#handleIntent(android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat,%20android.content.Intent)) in your `onStartCommand` as per the documentation.

You can use the [buildMediaButtonPendingIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html#buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(android.content.Context,%20long)) to construct a `PendingIntent` for various media buttons (such as play, pause, etc), which can then be set on your widget's buttons with [setOnClickPendingIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I still have one question, though. How can I track the session's state (current song metadata, playback state) from the app widget?

Comment: There isn't a synchronous way to get that information, so you'd need to use a service to update your widget. Then that service can connect via a `MediaBrowser` and create a `MediaController` from the session token.

Comment: @ianhanniballake How do I get about with the service? Do I start the service on widget enable and stop it on disable?

Comment: @Ishaan - that's not how a `MediaBrowserService` works, no. I'd suggest reading the [documentation on building a `MediaBrowserService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice.html). `MediaButtonReceiver` does the correct thing to trigger the correct [Media Session Callback](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/mediasession-callbacks.html)

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for the reply but I wasn't referring to MediaBrowserService. You've suggested that I need to use a service to update the widget and connect with the MediaBrowser. It was this service that I was referring to.

Comment: @Ishaan - 'that service' should be your `MediaBrowserService` - the service that knows about your playback state can update the widget directly as it updates its other state (its MediaSession, notification, etc).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks I understood. I am sorry I was getting confused since I am still new to MediaBrowserService.